# Limit non keyword args to a list in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been looking into args and parameters of a command for a while and I couldn't figure out how to create a list for keyword args. It works for normal arguments, but I was wondering if there was a way to apply this to keyword args.

```
@client.command()
async def prac(ctx, *arg):
    valid = {"valid" , "permit" , "allow"}
    if arg in valid:
        await ctx.send("You have sent: {}" .format(', '.join()))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Use valid arguments.")
```

The result I always get if of course the else statement `Use valid arguments.` I've seen a lot of bots use this concept in their commands but I just couldn't find out how they pulled it off.

Sorry if the answer is supposed to be obvious, any reply will be apprecited. Thanks~

Comment: Since `arg` is a list it's not going to match any of those strings.  Did you mean to say `if any(a in valid for a in arg):`?  (I assume you also meant to send the message `f"You have sent: {', '.join(arg)}"` to echo back the list of args...?)

Comment: for keywords you would need double `**` - popular in some examples `**kwargs`

Comment: @furas my bad i meant to say non keyword args, changing it now.

Comment: @Samwise i made this in a whim and i was a bit careless, but what i was looking for was `if any(a in valid for a in arg):`, so thanks for pointing out. But if you know, I want to ask how to have the else statement sent when at least one arg  is wrong. I tried args `valid` and `word` and the bot passed the if statement.

Comment: first you could see what you get - `print( arg )` - because `arg` should be a list and you should use `for`-loop check every value from this list separatelly. Or you should convert it to `set()` - `arg = set(arg)` - because your `valid = {...}` is a `set` - and then you may try set's functions like `if arg & valid:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `set()` in `valid` so you could convert `arg` to `set()` and use `set()` functions to compare them

```
valid = {"valid" , "permit" , "allow"}

arg = ['valid', 'allow']
arg = set(arg)

print( (arg & valid) == arg  ) # True
print( len(arg - valid) == 0 ) # True


arg = ['valid', 'other']
arg = set(arg)

print( (arg & valid) == arg  ) # False
print( len(arg - valid) == 0 ) # False
```

But first you have to check if `arg` is not empty because it will give `True`

```
arg = []
arg = set(arg)

print( (arg & valid) == arg  ) # True
print( len(arg - valid) == 0 ) # True
```

---

Other method is to use list comprehension with `any()` or `all()`

But again first you have to check if `arg` is not empty because it will give `True`

Code with `all()` is simpler

```
arg = ['valid', 'allow']
print('all:', all(x in valid for x in arg) ) # True

arg = ['valid', 'other']
print('all:', all(x in valid for x in arg) ) # False

arg = []
print('all:', all(x in valid for x in arg) ) # True
```

Code with `any()` needs two `not`

```
arg = ['valid', 'allow']
print('any:', not any(x not in valid for x in arg) ) # True

arg = ['valid', 'other']
print('any:', not any(x not in valid for x in arg) ) # False

arg = []
print('any:', not any(x not in valid for x in arg) ) # True
```

Comment: Thank you for all your effort! It was really helpful~~